# Can´t connect to mongodb server from Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, mongodb, google-app-engine, express, google-cloud-platform

I´m trying to connect my Google App Engine to my Google OneClick deploy mongodb Database.

I can access to my database from my localhost, I already run this command:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-mongodb --allow tcp:27017
```

But when I tried to access the same database from my Google App Engine I got this error:

```
/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:421
      throw err
      ^
MongoError: failed to connect to server [45.197.115:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connection 0 to 45.197.115:27017 timed out]
```

The app is in NodeJS.
I tried to use both, internal and external IP addresses and got the same message.

I´ll appreciate so much your help!
Thanks!

Comment: I am in the exact same position. Did you figure it out? If so could you answer the question or post some links. Thanks!